# AS3: How to reference a function in a namespace?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

AS3 is rather new to me. Let's say I have the following class defined in a separate file.

```
// saved as ./test/testing.as
package test{
   public class testing {
      public namespace nspc;
      nspc function hello(){
         trace("Hello World");
      };
   }
}
```

How can I call the hello() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is way of define namespace.

Basically you can use the namespace in as3 which have 3 steps.

**Defining namespaces**

File name should be `mynamespace.as`.  (*Should match with Namespacename*)

```
package test
{
    public namespace mynamespace; //Note here no class/interface declaration.
}
```

**Applying namespaces**

```
package test
{
    use namespace mynamespace;

    public class Testing
    {
        public function Testing()
        {   

        }

        mynamespace function hello():void //This method belongs to mynamespace
        {
            trace("Hello World");
        };
    }
}
```

**Referencing namespaces**

```
var testing:Testing = new Testing();
testing.mynamespace::hello();
```

(or)

```
use namespace mynamespace;

var testing:Testing = new Testing();
testing.hello();
```

Adobe article about namespace http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/namespaces.html

Answer (score 0):

With the [`use namespace`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#use_namespace) directive:

```
use namespace nspc;

var test:testing = new testing();
test.hello();
```

Comment: It says: Namespace was not found or is not a compile-time constant.